Best approach to map DTO to Kotlin Hibernate entity
I am in a situation where I have a complex entities and I'm really not sure what is the best practice in Kotlin/Spring/Hibernate to convert between DTO's and entities and vice versa.
So lets say I have ProductEntity :
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
data class ProductEntity(
    // ...other fields
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    val customer: CustomerEntity,


and a CustomerEntity
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
data class CustomerEntity(
    var name: String,
    var phoneNumber: String,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    var contacts: Set<ContactEntity>? = null,


So my issue is, how I am supposed to represent this kind of relationships in DTOs, having in mind that I will have to convert them to entities in order to persist them.
So lets I have a ProductDTO like this:
data class ProductDTO @JsonCreator constructor(
     @JsonProperty("customerId") var customerId: UUID,
)

Here I can represent customer as an UUID corresponding to its database entry, and when I provide this DTO to a function to persist it, I would have to fetch it from DB:
productService.persistProduct(producDto)

fun persistProduct(ProductDTO productDto) {
   val persistEntity = PersistEntity(
          customer = customerRepository.fetch(productDto.customerId)      
    )
    productRepository.save(peristEntity)

}

My only problem with this approach is that I would be making unnecessary db calls in case when I fetch entity first, convert it dto, update dto, and then try to persist it, in that case I'll be fetching same data twice.
The second approach is to keep all the data directly in the models, so ProductDto would have all the data from the complex dtos it contains:
data class ProductDTO @JsonCreator constructor(
     @JsonProperty("customerName") var customerName: String,
     @JsonProperty("customerPhoneNumber") var customerPhoneNumber: String,
     @JsonProperty("contacts") var contacts: Set<ContactDto>,
)

but converting that back to entity would make the quite complex right ?
productService.persistProduct(producDto)

fun persistProduct(ProductDTO productDto) {
   val persistEntity = PersistEntity(
          customer = CustomerEntity(name=productDto.customeName,
 contacts = *map productDto.contacts to Set<ContactEntity>*)     
    )
    productRepository.save(peristEntity)

}

Any opinion on how would you handle mapping of these complex relationships ?

Similar to MapStruct, there are some mapper tools for Kotlin, for example, https://github.com/YanneckReiss/KConMapper
@KConMapper(toClasses = [CreateExampleDTO::class, UpdateExampleDTO::class])
data class ExampleEntity(
    val uid: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
    val name: String,
    val timestamp: ZonedDateTime
)

Example of DTOs mapping to Entities.
// For the create case:
val createExampleDTO = CreateExampleDTO()
val exampleEntity: ExampleEntity = createExampleDTO.toExampleEntity()
    
// And for the update case:
val updateExampleDTO = UpdateExampleDTO()
val exampleEntity: ExampleEntity = updateExampleDTO.toExampleEntity()

Example of Entities mapping to DTOs .

val exampleEntity: ExampleEntity = ExampleEntity()
    
// For the create case:
val createExampleDTO: CreateExampleDTO = exampleEntity.toCreateExampleDTO()
    
// And for the update case:
val updateExampleDTO: UpdateExampleDTO = exampleEntity.toUpdateExampleDTO()


But personally, I would like process it directly by constructing a new DTO. In the real world applications, we could use different data structure and naming rules in DTOs.
val dto = ExampleDTO(
   name = entity.fullname,
   address = Address(
     street = entity.addreassStreet, 
     zipCode = entity.addressZipCode
   )
   ...
)


Update, it seems MapStruct also support Kotlin data class mapping, check the example project: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/main/mapstruct-kotlin

Thanks, will look into. So, if I understood correctly, this is based on keeping DTOs with all the data instead of only ids, and then a mapping mechanism can turn it back into entity ?

Check the KconMapper example, it also support converting back to entity.
